# led light is not responding over wifi from esp8266

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, led

Im trying to switch on and off led from from a local server created by esp8266.
Everything is working fine even esp also. Setup is working without ESP8266.

ESP is flashed with ESP8266_NONOS_SDK-2.2.0
Board used "Generic ESP8266 Module"
at COM Port 6

Arduino to bread board setup:-

pin 13 -> led
GND    -> led

Arduino to ESP setup before burning sketch:-

Arduino  -  ESP8266

3.3v     ->  vcc + CH_PD
GND+RST  ->  GND + GPIO0
TXD      ->  TX
RXD      ->  RX

Arduino to ESP setup before burning sketch:-

Arduino  -  ESP8266

3.3v     ->  vcc + CH_PD
GND      ->  GND
TXD      ->  TX
RXD      ->  RX

**COM output:**

Connecting to lan
.......
WiFi connected
Server started
Use this URL to connect: http://192.168.43.80/

I already tried:- 
using different pins
and also tried switching 
RXD->TX and TXD->RX

the problem what i think im getting is the communication between ESP and arduino. Although blue led in ESP flashes when i click on ON or OFF and im getting response in SERIAL MONITOR also:-

**COM OUTPUT:-**

new client
GET /LED=OFF HTTP/1.1
Client disonnected

new client
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Client disonnected

new client
GET /LED=ON HTTP/1.1
Client disonnected

new client
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Client disonnected

**Code I'm using:-**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "papa";
const char* password = "12345678ab";

int ledPin = 12; // GPIO13
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request

  int value = LOW;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    value = LOW;
  }

// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("On");
  } else {
    client.print("Off");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```